# How to handle error responses in XML-RPC?

Tags: java, xml-rpc, rpc

I'm using Redstone XML-RPC, but this question applies to all XML-RPC communication.

Given:

```
static interface Jira
{
    public String login( String username, String password ) throws XmlRpcFault;
    public void logout( String loginToken ) throws XmlRpcFault;
    public Issue findIssue(int issueId) throws XmlRpcFault;
}

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    Jira jira = ( Jira ) XmlRpcProxy.createProxy( "http://jira.atlassion.com/RPC2", new Class[] { Jira.class } );
    String token = jira.login( args[ 0 ], args [ 1 ] );
    jira.logout( token );
}
```

Say I invokoe the findIssue remote procedure. I am an authenticated user. Three things can happen:

1) The Issue object is found, I have authorization to use it, serialized remotely, and unserialized locally.
2) The Issue object is found, but I don't have authorization to use it.
3) The Issue object is not found.

2 and 3 are exceptions situations, but as far as I can tell XML-RPC doesn't support exceptions. If there were only cases 1) and 3), I could perhaps return a null Issue if it wasn't found, but since there are other possibilities, I need a more general solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't yet used the Redstone library yet but looking at the Javadoc, it does have an XmlRpcFault to use on the client side when you invoke a service which returns an error code, but I can't immediately see how to do it on the server.

In the case of Apache XML-RPC they explicitly didn't support it on the server and would always return 0. This library appears to have done things awfully similarly and the workaround you can employ is probably similar.

Essentially I threw a custom RuntimeException and then caught it at some other layer.  Ideally it would be possible to catch it at the servlet implementation but in my case I had to enhance several of their classes to correctly propagate the exception because they were using catch(Exception) all over the place internally.